# Product of i.i.d r.v. is Martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I face a problem where I need to show that the new r.v. that I create is a Martingale.

I set that $(X_i)_{i=0,1,\dots}$ is a r.v. with $E(X_i) = 1$ and that $Z_n = X_1\cdot X_2\cdot \ldots\cdot X_n$, then I need to show that $(Z_n)_{n=0,1,\dots}$ is a martingale.

I know that to say that it is a martingale, it has to fulfill those conditions:

- $E[|X_t|] < \infty$ for all t,
- $E[X_t|F_s] = X_s$ for all s < t.

Can I say that $E(Z_n) = 1^n$ and then say that it is a martingale ?

Comment: Well, what have you tried for the other one condition?

Comment: The other one condition I understand it: "If I have information until time s, the best guess for time t is the value in time s". But mathematically I struggle to "play" with it.

Comment: Do you know what $E(X_t|F_s)=X_s$ means [mathematically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_.CF.83-algebra)? Also, you might want to give a definition for $F_s$.

Comment: What do you mean by mathematically ? I understand that is the expected value of the r.v. X at time t given the filtration, the information we collected on the values of X up to time s

Comment: We learn that the expectation of x is the integral of x * f(x) dx but I don't see the utility here

Comment: No. What you are dealing with is "conditional expectation", not "expectation". Also, what is the context of your exercise? What is your background and what book are you reading on? The measure theoretical answer to your question would be very different from the one in the setting of discrete random variables.

Comment: We are finishing our quick overview of the stochastic processes with Martingales in a "Probability and Stochastic Processes" lesson. We use the book "Probability and Stochastic Processes" by Oloffson.

Comment: You probably need to postulate independence or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to show is for each $n$,
$$
E(Z_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=Z_n
$$
where $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$.

Now writing $Z_{n+1}=X_{n+1}Z_n$, you get
$$
E(Z_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=E(X_{n+1}Z_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=Z_nE(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=Z_nE(X_{n+1})=Z_n.
$$

---

One has $E(X_{n+1}Z_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=Z_nE(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)$ because $Z_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.

One has $E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=E(X_{n+1})$ because $X_{n+1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_n$ are independent.

You can check Corollary 3.7.3 in [Oloffson and Adersson's book](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/polofsson/teach/Book.pdf) you mentioned in the comment  for these two arguments if you don't have the measure theory background.

Comment: Thanks for the hint $Z_{n+1} = X_{n+1}*Z_n$. It makes sense to me now. You take out $Z_n$ out of the expected value, following $E(aX)=a*E(X)$, but why can we do that, if $Z_n$ is itself a product of $X_n$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I knew about the independence but not the first one. But does it mean I could have written $X_{n+1}*E(Z_n|F_n)$ and it would have been mathematically correct ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would you rephrase it?

Comment: The reason for being able to take out $Z_n$ in $E(X_{n+1}Z_n|F_n)$ is similar to $E(XY|X)=XE(Y|X)$.

Comment: In $*E(X_{n+1}*Z_n|F_n)$ you take out $Z_n$ to get $Z_nE(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)$.

Would it have been possible to take out $X_{n+1}$ instead ?

Comment: No. Just as you have $E(XY|X)=XE(Y|X)$ but in general not true that $E(XY|X)=YE(X|X)$.

Comment: Ok so that means here that $Z_n = F_n$ ? Where $Z_n$ is the multiplication of the $X_i$ and $F_n$ the collection of the $X_i$. Sorry if it seems obvious to you, but we can use the corollary you wrote because we have the same information in both $Z_n$ and $F_n$ right ?

Comment: Close. Though one should have $Z_n$ being $F_n$-measurable instead of $Z_n=F_n$ since $Z_n$ is a random variable both $F_n$ is the "information" given by $X_1,\cdots,X_n$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $$\mathbb{E}(Z_t|Z_s=z) = \mathbb{E}(z\cdot\Pi_{i=s+1}^tX_i) = z\cdot\Pi_{i=s+1}^t\mathbb{E}(X_i) = z.$$ This is the idea behind a martingale without getting bogged down in the measure theory. In essence, things aren't getting worse or better on average. Thus in expectation the future is simply the current realization.